# Font size unusually changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I've a problem with my very simple website. It seems that the font size unusually changes in some cases. For instance, when I click on a link in the homepage, the new page opened has a different font size. And it seems that this behavior happens only on Chrome. Please, see the pictures below. For each picture, on the left you can see the font size in the homepage and on the right you can see the font size in the page opened clicking on a link.

Internet Explorer (font size ok)

[image] 
[image]

Firefox (font size ok)

[image]
[image]

Chrome (font size is DIFFERENT)

[image]
[image]

This is my CSS code used by the two web pages (before this there's a reset standard file):

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;

}

.centered
{
    margin:0 auto;
}

.centered-content
{
    text-align:center;
}
div.article-header
{

    background-image:url(../img/articleheaderback.png);
    background-position:bottom;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:10px;


}
div.article-title
{
    width:69%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
div.article-more
{
    text-align:right;
    font-style:italic;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#690000;
    width:29%;
    padding-right:1%;
}
div.article-content
{
    width:94%;
    padding-right:3%;
    padding-left:3%;
}
div.article
{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:3%;
    padding-right:3%;
    width:94%;  
}
div.section
{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
div.section-title
{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    width:100%;
}
div.container
{
    width:100%;
    margin:10px 0;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#cbcb63;
}
div.content
{
    width:90%;
    background-color:#fff59b;
    margin:15px auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

div#contacts
{
    width:90%;
    background-color:#fff59b;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.dark-background
{
    background-color:#1b5e5e;
}
div.header
{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
div.footer
{
    text-align:center;
}
h1
{
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#690000;
}


img#logo
{
    max-width:100%;
}

li.basic
{
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    line-height:1.5;
}

li.nav
{
    color:#5c7304;
    padding-top:25px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
li.contacts
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:25%;
}
p
{
    line-height:1.5;
}
ul.nav
{
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
}
ul.basic
{
    list-style-type:disc;
    list-style-position:inside;
}
ul.contacts
{
    width:100%;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

This is the html homepage:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="it">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Responsive Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/princstyle.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, 
initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#section-list").hide();  

    $("#section-title").click(function(){
        $("#section-list").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- container contains HEADER + NAV + CONTENT-->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- header -->
        <div class="header">
            <img id="logo" alt="Logo: Matteo Puccinelli profile" src="img/logoridim.png"> 
        </div>

        <!-- sections -->
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Article: sections -->
            <div class="section">
                <div id="section-title" class="section-title">
                    <h1>
                        Sections
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div id="section-list">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="nav"><a href="prova.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav"><a href="#personaldata">Dati personali</a></li>
                        <li class="nav"><a href="#work">Esperienze lavorative</a></li>
                        <li class="nav"><a href="#education">Educazione</a></li>
                        <li class="nav"><a href="#passions">Passioni</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- content -->
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Article: personal data -->
            <div id="personaldata" class="article">
                <div class="article-header">
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <h1>
                            Dati personali
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="article-content">
                    <ul class="basic">
                        <li class="basic">Data di nascita: 18-01-1987</li>
                        <li class="basic">Luogo di nascita: Lucca</li>
                        <li class="basic">Nazionalità: italiana</li>
                        <li class="basic">Residenza: [privata]</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Article: work experiences -->
            <div id="work" class="article">
                <div class="article-header">
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <h1>
                            Esperienze lavorative
                        </h1>
                    </div><!--
                 --><div class="article-more">
                        <a href="work.html">+ more</a>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="article-content">
                    <ul class="basic">
                        <li class="basic">(dal 2011) Redattore per il portale <a href="http://www.libro-mania.com/" target="_blank">Libro-Mania</a>.</li>
                        <li class="basic">(dal 2007) Lavori occasionali.</li>
                        <li class="basic">(2011-2012) Tirocinio formativo presso l'azienda <a href="http://www.intecs.it/" target="_blank">Intecs SpA</a>.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Article: education -->
            <div id="education" class="article">
                <div class="article-header">
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <h1>
                            Educazione
                        </h1>
                    </div><!--
                 --><div class="article-more">
                        <a href="education.html">+ more</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="article-content">
                    <ul class="basic">
                        <li class="basic">(dal 2012) Laurea di secondo livello in Scienze Informatiche, facoltà di Scienze matematiche, fisiche e naturali di Pisa.</li>
                        <li class="basic">(2012) Laurea in Scienze Informatiche, facoltà di Scienze matematiche, fisiche e naturali di Pisa. Votazione 106/110.</li>
                        <li class="basic">(2007) Diploma di perito industriale capotecnico all'istituto industriale E. Fermi di Lucca con specializzazione Informatica. Votazione 100/100.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Article: passions -->
            <div id="passions" class="article">
                <div class="article-header">
                    <div class="article-title">
                        <h1>
                            Passioni e Hobby
                        </h1>
                    </div><!--
                 --><div class="article-more">
                        <a href="passions.html">+ more</a>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="article-content">
                    <p>
                        prova
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div> <!--content end -->
    </div> <!-- container end -->

    <!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer centered-content">
        <ul class="contacts">
            <li class="contacts"><img alt="facebook social icon" src="img/fbsmall.png"></li><!--
         --><li class="contacts"><img alt="twitter social icon" src="img/twittersmall.png"></li><!--
         --><li class="contacts"><img alt="feed RSS" src="img/rsssmall.png"></li><!--
         --><li class="contacts"><img alt="feed RSS" src="img/mail.png"></li>
        </ul>
        <p title="copyright" style="margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:15px;">
            Copyright 2013 Matteo Puccinelli
        </p>  
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you define font in `%` . it will be dynamic and prone to change with different _browser,resolution etc.._

Comment: what extensions do you have? Chrome is pretty compliant...

Comment: @MohammadAdil That wouldn't  explain why in some pages the font is different in others, though.

Comment: Do you have a link to your site we could see?

Comment: @Evan it does. If you don't set a base size for HTML, it's UA-defined. If you say, "I want 150% of what the browser thinks is correct", then your style depends on what the browser thinks is correct.

Comment: @JanDvorak I completely understand that, but why would what the browser *thinks is correct* change from *page to page* on the user's site in the same browser? (it seems like the OP is referring to the same pages, too, just in one sense it's opening from a link)

Comment: @superpuccio do you have a non-default zoom level by any chance?

Comment: This is most likely the effect of a non-default zoom level set. Note the green bars are thinner as well.

Comment: I checked this in JSFiddle and in both, font sizes displayed identically. I agree with Jan - check your browser zoom, and make sure it is 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, are you sure that the second page is at the same zoom level?

I would *think* that the problem is using % instead of em.

The first thing to do would be to determine if setting elements to em fixes the issue where the size changes on a new tab. After that, you can work out what em to set each element to.

```
*
{
    font-size: 20em !important;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1-** Font sizes in percentage are calculated based on a reference.

**2-** Font sizes are inherited.

In your case you have not defined a reference, so the browsers' default font sizes for **the parent** of those elements are the base for calculation.

Different browsers can have different default font sizes for the same element.

This is why you are seeing the difference.

You can set a font size on the body and then use percentages for anything else.

Answer (score 2):

em and % are pretty much the same thing - 2em = 200%.  Each browser has a default font-size for most things which are possible to overwrite.  Using * with !important is a very crude way of doing things because you will have to use !important if you want to override anything subsequently.

What you ideally need to do is to use:

```
html, body, table {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Additionally instead of using  to blank out the space between you footer navigation you can do this:

```
.footer ul {
    font-size: 1px;
}
.footer li {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hDLry/